# Count occurrence of a value in a data frame column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> This is the data frame

```
      Date     name 
0   2015-01-02  Adam          
1   2015-02-02  David         
2   2015-02-02  Adam          
3   2015-03-02  David         
4   2015-03-02  Hardik        
5   2015-03-02  David
```

> Now I want to count the occurrence of names month-wise and insert in count column.
> This is the expected output

```
      Date       name    Count
0   2015-01-02  Adam       1   
1   2015-02-02  David      1
2   2015-02-02  Adam       1
3   2015-03-02  David      2   
4   2015-03-02  Hardik     1
5   2015-03-02  David      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame((['2015-01-02',  'Adam' ],         
['2015-02-02',  'David'],         
['2015-02-02',  'Adam' ],         
['2015-03-02',  'David'],         
['2015-03-02' , 'Hardik'],        
['2015-03-02' , 'David' ]),columns=['Date','name'])
df['count'] = df.groupby(["Date","name"])["name"].transform("count")
```

|  | Date | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-01-02 | Adam | 1 |
| 1 | 2015-02-02 | David | 1 |
| 2 | 2015-02-02 | Adam | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-03-02 | David | 2 |
| 4 | 2015-03-02 | Hardik | 1 |
| 5 | 2015-03-02 | David | 2 |

**EDIT**

GROUP BY MONTH

```
df = pd.DataFrame((['2015-01-02',  'Adam' ],         
['2015-02-02',  'David'],         
['2015-02-02',  'Adam' ],         
['2015-03-02',  'David'],         
['2015-03-02' , 'Hardik'],        
['2015-03-02' , 'David' ]),columns=['Date','name'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['count'] = df.groupby(["name",pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')])["name"].transform("count")
```